# Is it possible to launch the C++ eth client without unlocking the accounts?

Tags: clients, accounts, cpp-ethereum, alethzero

Each time I run `eth` it requests my master password. I don't feel comforatble with permanently running a node with unlocked accounts.

[image: eth at start-up]

Is it possible to launch the C++ eth (or alethzero) client without unlocking the accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at this time. However you can set a password for individual accounts, in which case the strength of the master password would matter less.

Comment: The master password does not unlock the accounts? What does it do?